# Hide Reload action in Qt context menu

Tags: c++, qt, qwebengineview, qwebpage

I want to hide the `Reload` option from the default context menu of Qt webenginepage. I have already removed other options such as `Save page` and `View source` doing this :

```
WebPage::WebPage(QObject *parent) :
    QWebEnginePage(parent)
{
    action(QWebEnginePage::SavePage)->setVisible(false);
    action(QWebEnginePage::ViewSource)->setVisible(false);
    connect(QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile(), &QWebEngineProfile::downloadRequested, this, &WebPage::startDownload);
}
```

So I try to do the same for the `Reload` option like this :

```
action(QWebEnginePage::Reload)->setVisible(false);
```

But it doesn't work this time, any idea ?